# Upload an image using rest-client to sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to just upload an image from a ruby script to my server running Sinatra, and for the life of me I can't figure this out.

Here is what I have so far.

Server:

```
post '/uploads/:filename' do  
  File.open("./uploads/#{params[:filename]}", 'wb') do |f|  
    f.write(params[:filename].read)  
  end  
end
```

Ruby Script:

```
require 'rest_client'

RestClient.post("https://localhost:1337/uploads/image.jpg",
  :filename => File.new("C:\\Users\\ruby\\image.jpg", 'rb'))
```

The error Sinatra is showing is:
undefined method `read' for "image.jpg":String:

Which make sense, but I just don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you try by changing File.new to File.open?

Comment: Same error undefined method `read' for "image.jpg":String:

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Server:

```
post '/uploads/:filename' do
  @filename = File.join("./uploads/", params[:filename])
  @datafile = params[:data]
  File.open(@filename, 'wb') do |f| 
    f.write(@datafile[:tempfile].read)
  end
end
```

Client:

```
RestClient.post("https://server/uploads/#{file}.jpg",
    :data => File.open("#{file}.jpg", 'rb'))
```